# Samsung Smart TV Hangs on XHR

Tags: xmlhttprequest, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

I am making app that connects to a webpage that returns and XML RSS feed with images in it via XHR.  I then parse the xml and pull out image urls.  The code works in the emulator very well and displays all the images.  On the box/blue-ray player I am using to test the app it just hangs.

Any known differences between the emulator and real device for XHR?

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was that you could run into cross-domain policies problem. 
Is this XML file on remote server? If yes, try to put it inside application directory and try to run your application using this local version of XML.

As far as I know SDK's emulator doesn't care about cross-domain stuff.

If this won't help the problem is deeper.
Do you know how to use SDK console to debug application on real device ? 
Place in your code a lot of `alerts` in every part of logic. Then run your app and observe on console at what part it will hang.

That's all what I can help on this stage. When you find the place in code where it hang's I'm almost sure you'll find the solution, if not give me more info here - paste your code.

Comment: this problem got resolved today!  So happy, it turns out the internet connection on the box wasn't as great as I thought it was, switched connection type.  It works just as it did in the emulator.  Thanks for the reply.